# DataOutputStream is sending wrong data

Tags: java, tcp, tcpclient, dataoutputstream

I would like to apologise for my english. It's not my native language.

I'm trying to write simple TCP server and client. I have a problem with sending a number from client to server. 
Here is the code from client side:

```
public class ConnectionHandler {
  private InetAddress address;
  private int port;

  private Socket socket;
  private DataOutputStream dos;
  private DataInputStream dis;

  public ConnectionHandler(String ipAddress, String port) {
    try {
      address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
      this.port = Integer.parseInt(port);
      connectionHandle();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  private void connectionHandle() {
    try {
      socket = new Socket(address, port);
      dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

      getCatalogueList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  private void getCatalogueList() {
    try {
      dos.writeInt(1);
      sendFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  public void sendFile() {
    try{
      dos.writeInt(2);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Everything works fine when I'm sending number 1 in getCatalogueList(), but then in sendFile I'm trying to send number 2, but my server is getting 0. I've checked that if I'm sending numbers in one function:

```
private void getCatalogueList() {
  dos.writeInt(1);
  dos.writeInt(2);
}
```

everything works. Problem is only when I'm using two different functions.

If someone could help me how to prevent that and explain to me why this is happening I will be really grateful.

---

Server code (it's in C, I'm using bsd sockets)

```
int handleConnection(int clientSocket) {
  short connectionClosed = False;
  long action;

  while(!connectionClosed) {
    recv(clientSocket, &action, sizeof(int), 0);
    action = ntohl(action);
    printf("%i\n", action);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  const int port = 8080;
  const int maxConnection = 20;

  int listeningSocket, clientSocket;

  struct sockaddr_in server, client;
  struct hostent *host;
  socklen_t sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

  char myhostname[1024];

  listeningSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  gethostname(myhostname, 1023);
  host = gethostbyname(myhostname);

  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_port = htons(port);
  server.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr*) host->h_addr;

  if (bind(listeningSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    return -1;
  }

  listen(listeningSocket, maxConnection);
  while(True) {
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    clientSocket = accept(listeningSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &sin_size);
    if(fork() == 0) {
      handleConnection(clientSocket);
      close(clientSocket);
      exit(0);
    }
    else {
      printf("Waiting for connection.\n");
      continue;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) show your server code as well, (2) is this your *exact* code, or have you created an excerpt from a larger program, and (3) do you subclass `ConnectionHandler`?

Comment: I've added server code. It's part of a bigger program (client has GUI in swing), but that's all of the parts responsible for connection between server and client. I have only removed some lines responsible for sending (on server) and receiving (on client) file tree. I don't think they have any meaning here, because I'm using DataInputStream, not Output to do that. I can paste them if it will help. My ConnectionHandler doesn't extend any superior class if that is what you mean by subclass (I'm not sure if I understood u correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the count returned by `recv().` It could be -1, indicating an error page, or zero, indicating end of stream, or any positive value between 1 and `sizeof int` inclusive. Instead you're assuming it filled the buffer.

It has nothing to do with `DataOutputStream.`

You're also leaking client sockets in the parent process, and not checking for errors from `socket()` or `accept()` or `listen().`

Comment: Changing recv to if(recv(clientSocket, &action, sizeof(int), 0) != -1) didn't have any effect. I'm still getting 0 when trying to get 2

Comment: That's not a test for three different possibilities. There is no correct way to do that without storing the result into a variable.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what I should do. I mean, I'm sending int from client and receiving int on server. Now if I understood you correctly, I should do another recv to another variable and then it should be ok?

Comment: Sigh. Read what I wrote again. There are three possible results, and you need to test for all of them, including receiving some but not all of the data.

Comment: Ok, I can do it like that `int msg = recv(clientSocket, &action, sizeof(int), 0);` then I can make if-else statement for checking msg value. What conditions should I put in? `msg == -1`, `msg == 0` and `msg > 0 && msg <= sizeof(int)`? And what next? Ok, -1 is error and 0 is end of stream (so I assume I should while loop until 0 is reached?) and what in third scenario? I wander in the dark. If you could tell me step by step what to do.